# unable to submit spark python script

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I'm using the following script to submit a python script

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from pyspark.mllib.classification import LogisticRegressionWithSGD
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
from numpy import array
from pyspark import SparkContext as sc, SparkConf

data = sc.textFile("hdfs:/dataset/parkinsons.data")
```

got this error:

```
data = sc.textFile("hdfs:/dataset/parkinsons.data")
TypeError: unbound method textFile() must be called with SparkContext instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create a SparkContext at first, for example:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext(appName="TestApp")
data = sc.textFile("hdfs:/dataset/parkinsons.data")
```